# How to keep the parameter the same in gtest

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

Suppose the function

```
bool foo(int& num) {
     // do something and change the num
     return true;
}
```

Want the num to be the same before and after calling foo without caring what happens in foo.

Comment: What exactly does gtest have to do with this question?

Comment: Presumably you have no control over what `foo` does and can't change the prototype to accept `num` by value. Copy the argument into another variable and let `foo` mangle the copy.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass the parameter "num" as reference "&".
Pass it as value:
bool foo(int num) {...}
num outside foo() will stay the same.

Here is more about passing by reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_function_reference.asp

Comment: Changing the function under test in order to test it is futile. You're no longer testing what you need to test.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Copy the parameter value:

```cpp
int prev_num = num;
foo(num);
num = prev_num;
```

Solution 2: Use a wrapper

```cpp
// Wrapper uses pass by value for num
bool fooWrapper(int num) {
  return foo(num);
}

// Then later use the fooWrapper instead of foo:
fooWrapper(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to fuzzy to be sure what is proper answer.

Here is my guess:
I assume that you want test that `foo` do not change value of argument in some cases:

```cpp
struct Param
{
    int value;
};

class MagicFoo : public testing::TestWithParam<Param>
{};

TEST_P(MagicFoo, ArgIsNotChanged)
{
    auto x = GetParam().value;
    ASSERT_TRUE(foo(x));
    ASSERT_THAT(x, GetParam().value);
}
```

[Full live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fEMsnqEP3)